# How to create a custom search component in solr

Tags: solr

I'm trying to create a custom search component for solr to handle a special request. In that I want to search and check if the result number is empty or not. If it's empty I will try to update search condition and try to search again.

I need to do this because currently I have to query multiple times and check the result number and query again if the result is empty. And it costs a lot request to get the final result.

So I want to do it in solr server, then at client just send 1 request and have the final result.

I have follow this [tutorial](http://rockthecode.io/blog/plug-in-to-solr-5-creating-a-custom-search-component/). Then I check solr log but I didn't see "Hello world" was printed.

Here is my custom class

```
public class CustomQueryComponent extends SearchComponent {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CustomQueryComponent.class);

    @Override
    public void prepare(ResponseBuilder responseBuilder) throws IOException {
        LOG.info("Hello world");
    }

    @Override
    public void process(ResponseBuilder responseBuilder) throws IOException {
        LOG.info("Hello world");
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "CustomQueryComponent";
    }

    @Override
    public String getSource() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And my solrconfig.xml:

```
//...
    <searchComponent name="customQueryComponentDemo" class="com.company.CustomQueryComponent">
    </searchComponent>

    <requestHandler name="/search" class="solr.SearchHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
            <int name="rows">10</int>
            <bool name="preferLocalShards">false</bool>
        </lst>
        <arr name="first-components">
            <str>customQueryComponentDemo</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
//...
```

Solr logs when I access url http://localhost:6280/solr//select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true

```
INFO  - 2018-11-27 14:27:25.206; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=*:*&indent=true&wt=json} hits=9997 status=0 QTime=10
INFO  - 2018-11-27 14:27:28.204; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=*:*&indent=true&wt=json} hits=9997 status=0 QTime=6
INFO  - 2018-11-27 14:27:30.722; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=*:*&indent=true&wt=json} hits=9997 status=0 QTime=5
INFO  - 2018-11-27 14:27:35.080; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=*:*&indent=true&wt=json} hits=9997 status=0 QTime=3
```

Does anybody know why?
I'm looking forward your answers. Thanks a lot!
And sorry for not good English.

Comment: Are you sure your logging settings includes messages that have the identifier given back from your class name? Attach a debugger and run everything in debugging mode, try with a few printlns (which should end up in the log IIRC) and verify that your jar file is being loaded when you start Solr (it should be shown in the server startup log).

Answer (score 1):

I finnaly found out the problerm.
In solrconfig.xml, I defined `/search` request hander using my custom search component.
But when I test it, I used `/select`.

---

**For more information**:

You can check in console output if your jar file was loaded successfully or not via `grep` later lines after the line like this:

```
INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/../custom-search-component.jar' to classloader
```

Then goto Solr Admin page > collection_name > Plugins / Stats > QUERYHANDLER > your_custom_handler > description > Search using components. If you see your custom component in this list then it's done.
[Solr Admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MC31.png)

---

Thank you @matslindh for your advice.